# add foo to dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

How to add [same] foo to all keys of a dictionary such that

```
a = {'continent': ['America', 'South Africa'], 'country': ['USA', 'Egypt']}
```

becomes:

```
a = {'foo(bar=continent, hello=world)': ['America', 'South Africa'], 'foo(bar=country, hello=world)': ['USA', 'Egypt']}
```

EDIT:
I am actually looking to edit str key to non-str key, so:

```
a = {foo(bar='continent', hello=world): ['America', 'South Africa'], foo(bar='country', hello=world): ['USA', 'Egypt']}
```

Comment: Unrelated but South Africa isn't a continent

Answer (score 4):

```
a = {'foo(bar=' + key + ', hello=world)': a[key] for key in a.keys()}
```